# What “type” of language is JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Programming languages are often classified by their structure. To date there are many types, including (*but not limited to*): **Procedural**, **Structured**, **Object-Oriented**, **Concurrent**, **Functional**, **Event-Driven**, **Compiled**, and **Interpreted** (*[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20081224234420/https://www.giac.org/resources/whitepaper/architecture/97.php)*). Some programming languages are a mixture of these constructs, while others may fall under only one of the headings listed above.

My question is: **What type of language can JavaScript be classified as?**

Answer (score 40):

The [Javascript Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) tells you.

> JavaScript (/ˈdʒɑːvəˌskrɪpt/), often abbreviated as JS, is a programming language that conforms to the ECMAScript specification. JavaScript is high-level, often just-in-time compiled, and multi-paradigm. It has curly-bracket syntax, dynamic typing, prototype-based object-orientation, and first-class functions.

Paragraph three goes on to say:

> As a multi-paradigm language, JavaScript supports **event-driven**, **functional**, and **imperative** programming styles (emphasis added). It has application programming interfaces (APIs) for working with text, dates, regular expressions, standard data structures, and the Document Object Model (DOM).

Answer (score 16):

Regarding your selection of **Procedural**, **Structured**, **Object-Oriented**, **Concurrent**, **Functional**, **Event-Driven**, **Compiled**, and **Interpreted** as "types" of a computer language, Javascript is quite powerful; it is at least (or can be) **Procedural**, **Structured**, **Object-Oriented**, **Functional**, **Event-Driven** and **Interpreted**.

However, as your source says, many languages do not fall into one category only, but can be used in different ways. Even for example Java could be used in a rather strict procedural way.

And although Javascript supports functional programming, it is not the *lingua franca* of functional programmers - but they could use it, if they wanted to.

Javascript is so versatile, because it is prototype-based and because you can pass functions as parameters to other functions, which really allows for some crazy programming techniques (read: HACKS) combined with dynamic creation of Javascript it can be really powerful and confusing as well :)

You might want to look up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming for more explanations.

Comment: That was meant to be an 'example'.  I added that edit, I also added this line that I think you missed: Some programming languages are a mixture of these constructs, while others may fall under only one of the headings listed above.

Comment: Yap, I don't see any problems with my answer though.

Comment: JavaScript FTW!

Answer (score 0):

[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript)

...

JavaScript is a multi-paradigm, dynamic language with types and operators, standard built-in objects, and methods. Its syntax is based on the Java and C languages — many structures from those languages apply to JavaScript as well. JavaScript supports object-oriented programming with object prototypes, instead of classes (see more about prototypical inheritance and ES2015 classes). JavaScript also supports functional programming — functions are objects, giving functions the capacity to hold executable code and be passed around like any other object.

...

Answer (score -5):

JavaScript is an implementation of the ECMAScript language standard and is primarily used in the form of client-side JavaScript, implemented as part of a web browser in order to provide enhanced user interfaces and dynamic websites. This enables programmatic access to computational objects within a host environment.

Comment: This is plagiarized from some source ([Google](//google.com/search?q=%22implemented+as+part+of+a+web+browser+in+order+to+provide+enhanced+user+interfaces+and+dynamic+websites%22) finds many, _many_ variations of this paragraph), probably, without attribution and doesn’t answer the question adequately.